# How to perform chamfer matching on array of images in parallel to get list of distances?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing, gpu, matching

I have a working implementation of chamfer matching, and a huge array of  10,000 666x500p RGB-images, and a template. I am looking for distances for all these images, and I need the run time to be under 1 second.

I tried using the **`joblib`** with **`Parallel()`**, but I got a `MemoryError` exception.

```
def update_distances(predictions,obs_img,chamfer):
    distances = []
    size = predictions.shape[0]

    nprocs = 10                 # number of processes

    def process_image(img):     # function to be applied on all images
        return chamfer.chamferDistance_Compare(img,obs_img)

    # run `process_image()` in parallel
    distances.extend(Parallel(n_jobs=nprocs)(delayed(process_image)(predictions[idx]) for idx in range(size)))

    return distances
```

Are there any suggestions? Is the goal of performing this under 1 second even possible?

Execution time of one call to chamferDistance_Compare is about 1 ms.

Target machine is [Nvidia's Jetson Nano](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/autonomous-machines/embedded-systems/jetson-nano/)

Comment: Would you mind to post the complete MCVE-formulated problem? Missing the complete code. Missing the relevant DATA downscaled sub-sample. Missing the pystone()-performance and hardware-related details of a code-execution target machine. Would be also fair to post a nominal duration in [us], how long does it take to complete one call to **`chamfer.chamferDistance_Compare( img, obs_img )`** Best to measure like this: `from zmq import Stopwatch; aClk = Stopwatch(); aClk.start(); _ = chamfer.chamferDistance_Compare( img, obs_img ); d = aClk.stop(); print( "Per-call duration ~({0:})[us]".format(d))`